# Is there a setting/extension to disable HTML formatting in received Gmail messages?

Tags: gmail, formatting, html

I want all INBOX messages in gmail to appear in plain text.
When I read the messages I receive, 
I just want everything appearing in a consistent font and size of my choice.

No html formatting changing the size, boldness, color, etc.
I don't understand why this isn't a built-in option.

Maybe it is and I missed it?
Also would like to know if hotmail can do it.
I have already considered a workaround with Stylish but was hoping
for a solution that's simple enough that my parents could do it.

Comment: Ref. for Stylish?

Comment: Reference for stylish? Not following. You want to know what I'm referring to (a plugin that lets you modify CSS on any page you visit) or you want to know the workaround I'm referring to? The workaround would be something like adding * { font: 12px/14px Arial !important; } to the Stylish CSS rules for gmail.